# it is possible to scrape a web with variable column tables?

Tags: web-scraping

Good Morning,
I'm taking information from a web to feed a bbdd of products, and I've run into the next problem that I can not solve. The data I need is inside a tbody, and in the tr I can have these cases as an example

```
<tr id="2">
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="left"><nobr>1</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="right">2</td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>3</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>4</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>5</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>6</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>7</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>8</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>9</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="right">11</td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="right">12</td>
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr id="x">
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="left">1<nobr></nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="right">2</td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>3</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>4</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>5</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>6</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="right">7</td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="right">8</td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="right">9</td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>10</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>11</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="center"><nobr>12</nobr></td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="right">13</td>
<td class="tlin" valign="top" align="right">14</td>
</tr>
```

that is, the number of columns is not fixed. And I do not control when it makes the change of column, since all are called pull the same class. Does anyone have any idea how to alleviate it? Doing it by hand can be more hell since the products are more than 60,000

Thanks

Comment: columns are not any barrier here no matter how substantially they vary. You didn't even include any language tag. Are you expert on every language, I meant any solution from any language will do?

Comment: I'am php and python programmer

Comment: If you would like to go for python then I can offer some help. However, have you tried anything so far? If yes, you should update your post with that failure attempt so that we can start from there..